# What does 'the Harry Potterization of pop-culture' [in Star Wars] refer to?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/ctblauvelt/status/944701396854738945):

> Suffice it to say, it’s also the rebuke of the Harry Potterization of pop culture I’ve been looking for.

Now there is a book called [Harry Potterization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3659356883) - which appears to be talking about creating worlds in which you can sell merchandise and spin-offs.

There is a discussion about the [Harry Potterization of modern life](https://www.cookdandbombd.co.uk/forums/index.php?topic=61702.60), in which they appear to assume that Harry Potter invented the fans losing a sense of balance and proportion with a fun myth, and dressing up and going nuts about it.

There is a discussion stating the [Harry Potterization of Star Wars](http://starwars1999.tumblr.com/post/61534887062/midi-chlorians-and-the-harry-pottering-of-star) is about how midi-chlorians involve 'being born with it' and eliminate the idea of democratic spiritual progress opportunity open to all.

The original discussion [referred to it](https://twitter.com/ctblauvelt/status/944711930962432000) as a kind of 'small world of relationships' in which you first crush is your spouse and everyone is related. (But arguably that was always there in Star Wars).

My question is: **What does 'the Harry Potterization of pop-culture' [in Star Wars] refer to?**

Comment: Does the next tweet not answer this? "The Potter stories suggest everyone’s related, the person you crush on in middle school will be your spouse – “mythic” storytelling has rarely been so small, so juvenile, so petty. Johnson’s film shuns all of that – and Hollywood’s current “plot is everything” approach."

Comment: "*This book looks at “Harry Potterization” through the lens of Malcolm Gladwell’s Tipping Point: How Little Things Make a Big Difference. The implications of Tipping points are highlighted to develop the brands within their wider brandscape in order to be a sustainable relationship brand. Harry Potter brand is tipped through its influential and yet delivers memorable message while interfering the situations and context impending.* - I'm guessing that if this is indicative of the quality of writing of the book, that the rest is also garbage.

Comment: I had an opinion that Star Wars initially was designed to sell merch as well, long before Harry Potter arrived. So the 'potterization' of SW makes no sense to me.

Comment: It sounds like the original discussion (small world fantasy) referenced by OP and @TheLethalCarrot is probably what they're talking about. This fits with what TLJ reveals about Rey's parents - I'm guessing that's the way in which TLJ is the "rebuke of [...] Harry Potterization" they were looking for.

Comment: @TimSparrow, especially since in Star Wars (original and first sequel trilogy) everybody was related or had at least a shared history (for broadly the same reason that many people were related in "How the West Was Won").

Comment: If that's your definition of Harry Potterization, then George Lucas Harry Potterized Star Wars a couple of decades before J K Rowling put pen to paper. My personal theory is that Harry Potter is the Star Warsization of The Worst Witch.

Comment: Thanks @Bob - could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: … and then the next Star Wars movie rebuked the rebuke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

His next tweet answers this. He's referring to "[small universe syndrome](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Media_Franchising/dEBsiqOOD9QC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22small%20universe%20syndrome%22&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover)", where every character and plot element ultimately turn out to be related to every other character and plot element in some fashion (e.g. Harry's best friend's parents turn out to be part of the same organisation that his own parents were part of, he marries his best friend's sister, his best friend's rat turns out to be a spy for his nemesis, his future wife gets taken over by his nemesis, etc etc)

> The Potter stories suggest everyone’s related, the person you crush on
> in middle school will be your spouse – “mythic” storytelling has
> rarely been so small, so juvenile, so petty. Johnson’s film shuns all
> of that – and Hollywood’s current “plot is everything” approach.
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/ctblauvelt/status/944711930962432000)</sup></sub>

Marvel VP Justin Lambros suggested that the best way to prevent this was to "silo" different properties, giving showrunners and directors broad info about canon, but letting them generate their own characters and plotlines and their own "cool ideas" without constantly "calling back" to earlier shows and films in order to provide connection.

Comment: What, Valorum, are you combing through the archives for old questions lacking answers?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Some of these have been bugging me for a while

Comment: But again, Star Wars had already done this.

Comment: @Spencer - HP dialled that up to 11